# Do I need to open a Pokemon game to add the Pokemon to my Pokedex?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-bank

I am trying to build a living Pokédex in Omega Ruby, and I just transferred all my caught Pokémon from X to the Pokémon Bank. Now I want to add those Pokémon to my Pokédex in OR, so I can see which Pokémon I still can catch in the wild.

I assume I need to transfer them from my Bank to the computer in Omega Ruby, and start-up Omega Ruby. Is this correct, or do I need to do something special (such as having them in my party, to trigger the adding to the Pokédex?)

Comment: You should only need to start the game after the transfer from your bank. Anyway you can just try with a bunch of unregistered Pokemon and see if it works.

Comment: I just removed the pokemon-bank tag the other day. Please see our guidelines on [how to tag Pokemon questions](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/pokemon-tag-problems-gotta-tag-em-all/6958#6958). If you think an amendment needs to be made, please propose one before enacting changes on the site.

Comment: @StrixVaria Sorry. I thought it was a good idea to create the pokemon-bank tag. Thanks for rollbacking  everything

Comment: @Mathias711 Honestly, it may be. I was just enacting the rules as we have them now, but I'm not familiar with the details of Pokemon Bank. If you still think it's a good idea, you can make a case for it in the linked meta topic.

Comment: @StrixVaria I posted my recommendation in the topic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pokebank, just transfer them to PC box in your ORAS game and save. You don't need to close Pokebank at all... Once you save the changes, they'll register to your Pokedex in ORAS.

Once you're on the Pokebank title screen, you can boot up Pokebank again and put another batch into your ORAS boxes.

Comment: Okay, that is different from what I thought. That can be important when you have not enough empty boxes in ORAS available. Do you have any sources for this, or did you try it out by yourself?

Comment: I've done it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can transfer your living Pokedex from Pokebank to the PC of your ORAS game.

You do not need to actually "unlock" the PC boxes ingame first to do this -- they're all visible in Pokebank even if you just started a new game and haven't caught anything yet.

Source: I did this myself and it worked fine.

Comment: I thought you need to get to a point where you have your Pokedex?

Comment: @FezodgeIII: Oh yeah, that too.